# Windows 8 RT online Flash Movie

Tags: c#, flash, xaml, video-streaming, windows-8.1

I'm programming a Windows 8 RT app that uses the API of Rotten Tomatoes. It gives me access to trailers/clips of the selected movie. I checked out the link and it appears all of the links are online Flash movies.

I tried playing around with the 'WebView' control and the 'MediaElement', but none seem to satisify my needs.
Is it even possible to play Flash movies. If not what are my options?

Comment: Can you post a sample link of flash video?

Comment: This is sample link. The video is embedded in the page. http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/last_vegas_2013/trailers/11178829

Comment: Does the API give you link for whole page rather than only flash video URL like [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/embed/oDAw7vW7H0c)?

Comment: I only get the link I provided in the answer above. Not a direct link to the movie.

Answer (score 0):

If you code like this `<WebView Source="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/last_vegas_2013/trailers/11178829" />`, you can see it's opening whole page. Good thing is that video gets play. So you need to remove the non-relevant portion using [InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh738508) method & JavaScript. I don't know too much JS otherwise I would have give you proper solution.

I am confident JS will help you, the reason is [this app itself](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/d8dba166-2bd6-48fa-8856-f01c63725d2a). It's basically a Facebook website with RELEVANT portion.

**Disclaimer: I am not the owner of that app.**

Also check out [this](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/123551) feature request.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it seems the Webview control has no ability to play Flash videos. Anyway I'm just opening a link to the webpage. Not as nice looking.